# Which lines need semicolons for Dean Edwards Javascript packer?

Tags: javascript, packer

So his [help site](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/usage/) states that "All statements, including function declarations, must be correctly terminated with semi-colons."

But in this [sample code](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/usage/sample.html), he specifically say *not* to end the if statement in semicolon.

So is there a complete list of what should be ended with a semicolon? I was looking at my Javscript code and here are some cases I wasn't sure was *proper* format for the packer:

1)

```
for( i in cities ) {
    alert( i );
};
```

2)

```
var map = {
    city : 'atlanta',
    year : 1987
};
```

3)

```
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {
    content : content_div,
    zIndex  : INFO_WINDOW_Z
}; );
```

4)

```
var options = {
    business : business,
    columns  : [ 'url', 'image_url', 'expiration', 'percent_discount', 'claimed', 'fine_print' ];
};
```

5)

```
$( warp_content ).hover( function() {
    $( deal_description ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
};, function() {
    $( deal_description ).fadeOut( 'fast' );
}; );
```

Comment: Note how that page says "this page needs to be updated for version 3.0". I tried some code without semicolons and it all appears to work just fine; I assume the semicolon warning is outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are rules, but sometimes they may not be obvious. Essentially, the following statements do *not* need terminating semicolons:

- `if (...) { }`
- `for (...) { }`
- `while (...) { }` (except in `do { } while (...);`)
- `function (...) { }` (except for examples such as `var f = function() { };` where an anonymous function is part of a larger statement)
- `try { } catch (...) { }`
- `with (...) { }`

Essentially, anywhere `{ }` surrounds a group of *statements*, that is a *block* and no terminating semicolon is required.

Comment: This is a good answer, but to clear up one potential ambiguity: in `var x = function () { ... }` you need the semicolon, because even though the `{ ... }` surrounds a group of statements, it appears inside a statement that does need a semicolon.  If the next statement was `(function () { ... })();` then leaving the `;` off the end of the `var` would cause the meaning of the program to change.

Comment: Well the packer said that function declarations need to end with semicolons like this `function() {};`, what about objects like 'var map = { this : 'that' };`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Thanks, I clarified my answer.

Comment: @hobbes3, `function () {};` can be a function value when used inside an expression, but it cannot be a function *declaration* since it has no name.  Function *declarations* need not end with a semicolon.

Comment: @hobbes3: Objects like `{ this : 'that' }` use curly braces as part of the *object literal syntax*, not as a *block of statements*.

Comment: @hobbes3, Yes, you need a semicolon after `var map = { "this": "that" }`.  Try running `var map = { "this": "that" } /* newline here */ (function () { }());` and see what happens without the semicolon.